# Starvation and threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an interesting scenario based question related to java threads.

Sam has designed an application. I t segregates tasks that are critical and executed frequently from tasks that are non critical and executed less frequently. He has prioritized these tasks based on their criticality and frequency of execution. After close scrutiny, he finds that the tasks  designed to be non critical are rarely getting executed. From what kind of problem is the application suffering?

I have figured it out as "Starvation" but i am still confuse whether I am right or wrong.

Comment: You'll probably find the answers to your tutorial questions in the lecture notes or textbook.

Comment: Mind sharing *why* you think the problem is starvation?

Comment: I think it more for Computer Science site than SO.

Comment: The hostility to this question seems unnecessary. I believe that starvation is correct. .

Answer (score 1):

Starvation is a reasonable term for what is going on here.  However, your lecturer *might* have something more specific in mind (... I'm not sure what ...) so check your lecture notes and text books.

---

> ... i am still confuse whether I am right or wrong.

If you stated *why* you are confused, we might be able to sort out your confusion.